# Почему в аргументе функции выводит ошибку?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
почему если я передаю в качестве аргумента сам список, то выдает ошибку, но если список приравнять к переменной, и передать ее, то ошибки не будет?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код в картинках зло, но тут все просто - вы нигде не передаете никакой список. Вы определяете сигнатуру метода всего лишь. И делаете это неправильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не совсем понимаете, как работает объявление функции.
Когда вы объявляете функцию, в скобках вы указываете имя переменной, которая будет использоваться в функции. Пользователь будет передавать в эту функцию объект при её вызове, а объект будет присваиваться этой переменной в коде функции.
То есть, к примеру:

```
def my_function(a):
```

В этой строке задаётся локальная переменная a, которая будет использоваться в самой функции. К примеру, мы хотим, чтобы функция возвращала нам отсортированный список. Мы пишем такой код:

```
def my_function(a):
    return sorted(a)
```

Обратите внимание, что переменная `a` - локальная переменная функции и не связана с переменной `a` во всём коде, если таковая есть.

А когда  мы вызовем эту функцию, то мы можем передать в неё список:

```
spisok = my_function([2, 5, 4, 1])
```

Или:

```
numbers = [2, 5, 4, 1]
spisok = my_function(numbers)
```

После этого в переменной `spisok` будет отсортированный список чисел, который мы передали в функцию.
То есть функция приняла список, обозначила его как переменная `a` в теле самой функции, совершила некие действия и вернула нам список.
Надеюсь, что мой ответ помог разобраться в вашем вопросе.
Советую почитать больше про функции в Python [здесь](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp).